# Is there any way to keep my minecraft server from going through the day/night cycle when no one's online?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

My friends and I use the day number as part of our server rules, so we want to keep the day from changing while we're offline, but the only way I know of to do that is to stop the server from running...

Answer (score 32):

You should be able to use command blocks to automatically detect whether players are online or not, then appropriately set the `doDaylightCycle` rule appropriately.  Try placing the following setup in the server spawn chunks:

[image]

(Piston is a sticky one.)

The general idea is that the left command checks for online players a few times every second and the comparator next to it will only output a signal if there is at least one player online.  Once everyone logs off, the piston retracts and turns off the day/night cycle.  As soon as someone logs in again, the comparator will turn on again and toggle the day/night cycle back on.

Comment: Beat me to it.  Nonetheless, good answer; +1.

Comment: You should be able to replace the torch/repeater/solid block setup with a redstone block on the sticky piston.

Comment: I was worried that would just trigger both commands on each update, but after testing it, replacing the solid block with a redstone block does indeed work.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to @SpectralFlame's solution that works with a setblock/fill clock (for reduced lag), you can use the following two commands (in this order):

```
gamerule doDaylightCycle false
execute @p ~ ~ ~ gamerule doDaylightCycle true
```

The second command will fail when there is no player to execute on, meaning the result of the first command won't be immediately overridden.

Comment: I might not be understanding something, but wouldn't a fill clock contribute to more lag since you'd be executing the commands 3-5 times as often?  Or is redstone lag just THAT bad?

Comment: @SpectralFlame IIRC the main problem with redstone lag are the many block and lighting updates. Compared to that, a simple gamerule change, even when done 40 times a second, should not affect the game at all.

Comment: In addition to that, using the Repeat and Chain type command blocks introduced in the latest snapshot/1.9 removes the need for the fill clock as well, making it both easier to use and probably even more lag-free.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on version 1.8+ (which i suspect you are, for you have not specified any version) then the following will help:

When the last person gets off the server, they should type the command `/gamerule doDaylightCycle false` this will stop the sun/moon from moving.

When the first person gets back online, you can do `/gamerule doDaylightCycle true` to start it back up.

Otherwise, you can put command blocks with these commands in them in an admin-only spot where you people will go when the last/first person gets on/off.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of server are you running?  By default most servers will keep the sawn chunk loaded all the time.

I think this may work, but I haven't actually tested.  If you are running a server that supports adding the [Multiverse-Core](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/multiverse-core/) then you can change the option `keepSpawnInMemory` to keep the spawn chunks loaded.  I suspect, but am not certain, that if no chunks are loaded then they time would basically stop.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that keeping (or not keeping) spawn chunks loaded does not stop the daylight cycle.